# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException{"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'by'."}

Tags: visual-studio-2017

```
{      
       STDB.Open();
       string query = $"INSERT INTO  [dbo].[Inbound](Trailer#, Shipper#, 
       Seal#, Recieved By, Recieving Shift, Carrier, Supplier, Vendor, 
       Contents, Location, Comments) VALUES ('{textBox1.Text}', 
       '{textBox2.Text}','{textBox3.Text}', '{comboBox5.Text}', 
       '{comboBox1.Text}','{comboBox6.Text}', '{textBox4.Text}', 
       '{textBox5.Text}',' {comboBox2.Text}', '{comboBox3.Text}', 
       '{textBox6.Text}')";
       SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, STDB);
       SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
       STDB.Close();
       MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

(This is a filler text from the editor, because this post was originally posted as just only the code but without the code format, I've edited the code to make it at least a bit more readable for the others)

Comment: Fix your code format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want the , after the by.  You want the command after the first field in the by.  If a column has a space in the name surround the field name is [ ]

```
{ STDB.Open(); string query = $"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Inbound](Trailer#, Shipper#, Seal#, Recieved By [Recieving Shift], Carrier, Supplier, Vendor, Contents, Location, Comments)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. It gives another exception now saying that trailer# is an invalid column name..So any idea if we can use '#' symbol for naming the columns?

Comment: try putting all the column names in [ ]